# ...Ароматнее, в конце концов(,) полезнее, а также посъедобнее

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, однородные-члены

Нужна запятая?

> Это блюдо прям шик-шик, особенно когда ты ешь рыбчонку или мясчонко, в духовке насухо запечённое, — щовель, относительно жидкий, делает вкус этой сухомятины свежее, ароматнее, в конце концов(,) полезнее, а также посъедобнее.

Comment: Думаю, нет, поскольку вводное слово разделяет однородные члены, следовательно запятая не нужна.

Comment: Сравнительная степень от "съедобный" режет мой слух: пища либо съедобная, либо нет. Здесь как со "2-ой свежестью" в известном романе М.А. Булгакова.

Comment: Меняйте текст.  Мясчонко  с рыбчонкой  обсуждайте с котами.  Там же свои собственные блюда. Надоел развязный стиль этих текстов.  Нормальных тем за ними не видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [§ 94.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127) Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения)...

[в конце концов](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/86/%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2)
**1.** Наречное выражение. То же, что «после всего, в конце, в завершение, напоследок». Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
**2.** Вводное выражение, обозначающее недовольство, нетерпение, раздражение или указывающее на то, что соотносящееся с ним высказывание является заключительным в сообщении говорящего. Выделяется знаками препинания (обычно запятыми).

*Свежее, ароматнее, полезнее* — это однородные члены.
Пожалуй, это именно тот интересный момент, когда не важно, **чем** считается в этом предложении "в конце концов", важно, что запятая тут в любом случае не нужна.

Если хочется все-таки сделать выразительную паузу, то можно в указанном месте фантасмагорического предложения поставить тире:
*...свежее, ароматнее, в конце концов — полезнее...*

P. S. Просто к сведению:
• [щ**а**вель](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/272294);
• за всяко-разно накрученными смыслами и словечками теряется идея, полезность — *ценность!* — вашего вопроса. Пока извертишься и разберешься, в чем суть...

Comment: *Щовель* — моё собственное блюдо.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи предложение **нужно редактировать:**

*...делает вкус этой сухомятины свежее, ароматнее, **в конце концов,** а также полезнее **и** съедобнее.

**Пояснение**

У нас **4 однородных члена и вводное слово.**

При постановке **запятой** возникает проблема с отнесенностью вводного слова к одному из членов предложения. ПАС предлагает не выделять вводное  слово запятой, но и это в данном случае  **не решает проблему**.

Тогда нужно **иначе оформить ряд,** используя союзную связь.